# Debo traspasar todos los cursos que han realizado 1000 personas durante el año 2023, tengo el rut para identificar

Tags: excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cursos de empleados extraer datos desde una planilla a otra hoja

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema cual es?

Comment: Tengo una planilla que me arroja a todos los empleados y sus cursos, estos van ordenados segun rut y nombre, por lo que si la persona realizo 5 cursos diferentes, se duplica su rut y nombre, la información esta ordenada de forma horizontal. Como muestra la imagen.

Comment: necesito saber los nombres de los cursos que han realizado solo 1000 empleados de 2000 que aparecen, y tengo el rut para buscar.

Comment: Lo que has puesto como comentario, debe ser una edición a la pregunta. Además, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Eso asumiendo que estás usando un lenguaje de programación para ello.

Comment: Llevatelo a una tabla dinámica y así podrás saber fácilmente qué cursos ha hecho cada usuario. Luego solo filtra los 1000 usuarios que te interesen

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan otros colaboradores este espacio está destinado a resolver problemas unos con otros en código o algún avance en proyectos y desarrollos; sin embargo comprendo tu necesidad en cierto grado, espero que esto te funcione.

Lo que puedes aplicar es lo siguiente:

Obtuve una muestra de los registros con los que cuentas la información de las personas y cursos está alterada, pero los identificadores como el RUT que utilizas se mantienen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apliqué una fórmula sólo en caso de que esa información te sirva para conocer el número de cursos (sin importar el nombre) por persona en la columna G.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para finalizar en el menú **Insertar** elijo **Tabla dinámica**.

Pongo el **RUT** en *Filas*, el **Nombre de la Actividad** en *Columnas* y nuevamente arrastro el **Nombre de la Actividad** como Valores con la descripción **Cuenta de Nombre de la Actividad**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está la configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuevamente espero que esta información te sirva, saludos.